# How do I set up a "masked" domain?

Tags: networking, dns, domain, whm

I am working on a web application that can be access via resellers who can use their own domain and have a customised portal based on this domain.

e.g

Main web application lives at www.myapplication.com.

Reseller A, has their own domain name, www.resellerapplication.com. This is assigned in my database and has a reseller specific logo assigned to it. (this bit I can do by checking the referring URI)

Visiting www.resellerapplication.com, the user will see the application, but with the reseller logo in the corner.

So, how do I go about setting up the domain, www.resellerapplication.com, to act as a "mask" for my domain? URLs need to work the same, so www.resellerapplication.com/contact-us will show www.myapplication.com/contact-us etc etc.

I *think* the reseller domain needs an A Record setting up to point to the IP of my domain, but then I'm lost. Again, I *assume* I need to set up a VirtualHost, but can't see how to do this in WHM/cPanel.

Is there another/easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the masking with the cPanel by following this short tutorial:

1. Log into the cPanel manager using the credentials provided by the company that registered the domain. Once logged in, look for the "Domain" or "Account" manager to access the needed domain options.
2. Click the option listed for "Forward" and then click "Forward Domain." The forwarding information currently being used should be displayed.
3. Click the link labeled "Advanced Options" to configure the masking options.
4. Select the option to "Forward with Masking" to prevent the URL visitors to the site are being sent to from being displayed in the browser's navigation bar. Click "OK" to save the changes.

**UPDATE**: Almost every provider offers an option like that. You have to check their individual websites. Even if they don't offer a cPanel they offer another option to mask the redirects. I've checked 123-reg and GoDaddy and they both offer that.

[Source](http://www.ehow.com/how_8669743_set-up-domain-masking-cpanel.html)

Comment: Will this work for ANY domain? It is plausible resellers will be buying domains from any provider ie. 123-Reg, Namesco, GoDaddy etc. I need something that will work for any kind of account (Not all domain accounts will have cPanel access?)

Comment: Yes, almost every provider offers an option like that. You have to check their individual websites. Even if they don't offer a cPanel they offer another option to mask the redirects. I've checked 123-reg and GoDaddy and they both offer that. (I've updated my answer)